# Number related puzzle. But not even close to math. What is it?

Tags: pattern

If 1 + 9 +   8 = 1,

What is 2 + 8 + 9?

Looking forward to your answers ;)

Comment: Welcome to puzzling SE. This far from being a good puzzle. You are asking people in here to try to guess a pattern you have in mind offering a single example. You should either show more examples following the same pattern or add more clues about the pattern you have in mind. Also, not sure if the riddle tag is the best one on this case.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. Wha tag would you use in this case?

Comment: I don't know, because your puzzle is ambiguous. Check the description of the tags and see what fits. maybe pattern or something like that.

Comment: The answer is 2 and you're in base 17.

Comment: Not bad Ian, but that is pretty close to math, unlike what the title suggest :P

Comment: Here is an other possibility that does not involve math. Answer is 1 because if you overlap the digits you get one circle overlapping for at least 2 digits. I know it's the wrong answer, but you should expect things like this when you ask ambiguous  questions.

Comment: Ok guys, stop removing his reputation points like jerks. He just joined the community 5 minutes ago... give him a chance and perhaps a few polite advises. And to speak in a language the point greedy folks might understand, he won't be able to upvote anyone if he doesn't get at least a few reputation points...

Comment: @stackreader Well said. I upvoted this :) Downvotes scares beginners and won't attract too many if it goes on like this.

Comment: @stackreader Thank you. Appreciate that. I'm willing to learn. I really like the riddles on this site.

Comment: @TristandeJager Your puzzle was nice and interesting, only important thing for next time would be to add at least 1 more example that fit the logic so we can extrapolate similarities and eliminate irrelevant solutions.

Comment: @stackreader Yes I understand, I won't let you down next time ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It could be

> 10

Since  1 + 9 + 8 = 1

> **O**ne + **N**ine + **E**ight initial letters spell **ONE**
>
>  2 + 8 + 9 gives **T**wo + **E**ight + **N**ine spells **TEN**

Comment: You got it right Tom! Sorry for the ambiguous puzzle all.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling!   Thanks for the quick response and am sure you can make another puzzle -  tough with a unique answer!

Answer (score 1):

There can be many answers to this in the current situation of the question -

Here goes one -

Answer is

> 2+9+8 = **2**

Explaination

> one nine eight = 1  (Number of t's in the digits)
>
>  two eight nine = 2 (Number of t's in the digits)

Again, its too broad and ambiguous.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Not the answer I had in mind, but you are not wrong! My fault in this case because of the broad question.

Comment: No problems. All the best for the next one! Keep puzzling