# A mathematic riddle

Tags: riddle, mathematics

A mathematic riddle:

> If $1+9+8=1$, what is $2+8+9$?

I know, many of you out-of-the-box-thinkers, I really like it,
but please don't give answers to this riddle as $1=0$ and $9=0$ and $8=1$, that's why $1+9+8=1$.

Good luck!

As it has been solved [here](https://ceretrain.com/riddle-72) is the link for the puzzle.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be your riddle, looking it up online comes back with dozens of hits, so could you show where you found it?

Comment: Yes, but it has the answer with it.

Comment: For sources that provide the answer, mention that the puzzle is from elsewhere and then add the source once the puzzle is solved. [See here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/is-it-acceptable-to-post-a-puzzle-from-another-source-and-edit-in-attribution-on)

Comment: Just realised this is actually a duplicate on PSE - d'oh! See [Number related puzzle. But not even close to math. What is it?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44839/number-related-puzzle-but-not-even-close-to-math-what-is-it) Totally didn't spot that before I answered (and only thought to check at all because BG spotted it elsewhere on the web)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 + 8 + 9 is:

> **10**

Because:

> We need only look at the first letters of each number when spelled out as words:
>
>   **O**ne + **N**ine + **E**ight = **ONE** (1)
>
>  Thus:
>
>  **T**wo + **E**ight + **N**ine = **TEN** (10)